Dynamically specify which table to query at runtime
I have many tables that can be fetched. Right now, for each table I have a Controller class that gets the request, applies the query params and paging, and finally returns the result. All of them are pretty much the same and only the table name is different, which resulted in many files and many duplications.
So, I was trying to create one endpoint and serve all of them. The goal was to detect the table from route parameter.
First I created this Attribute:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class ResourceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ResourceAttribute(ResourceType resourceType)
    {
        ResourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public ResourceType ResourceType { get; }
}

public enum ResourceType
{
    Public = 1,
    User,
    Admin
}

Public means anyone can fetch the data, example: Product. User means the resource is available for each logged-in user and they should not see other users' data, example: Review, Order. And Admin means this resource is only available in our admin panel and it is not public, example: AppSettings.
Next, I apply the attribute:
[Resource(ResourceType.Public)]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}

Then I created a singleton service to store all resource information:
public class ResourceService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, RoutableResource> _resourceMap;

    public ResourceService()
    {
        _resourceMap = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .Where(x => x.IsDefined(typeof(ResourceAttribute), false))
            .ToDictionary(
                GetResourceRouteName,
                x => new RoutableResource
                {
                    Name = GetResourceRouteName(x),
                    Type = x,
                    ResourceType = GetResourceRouteType(x)
                });

        // ...
    }

    public bool ResourceExists(string resourceName) => _resourceMap.ContainsKey(resourceName);
    public RoutableResource? GetResource(string resourceName) => _resourceMap.GetValueOrDefault(resourceName);
}

public class RoutableResource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public ResourceType ResourceType { get; set; }
}

And this is the controller method:
[HttpGet("{resourceName}/{id?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetResource(string resourceName, string? id)
{
    if (!_resourceService.ResourceExists(resourceName))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    RoutableResource resource = _resourceService.GetResource(resourceName)!;
    
    // Check authorization

    // Get IQueryable of the selected resource  [I'm stuck here]

    // Get all query params and apply them to query with the help of reflection and expressions

    // Get the target ViewModel class from ResourceVM map and apply the projection

    // Finally return the result
}

There is a DbContext.Set<T>() but it requires the type at compile time. With the help of this answer I got an IQueryable but it was not useful.
All my entities except for join table entities have a base interface (join tables are not directly queryable anyway):
public interface IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IComparable, IConvertible, IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public TKey Id { get; init; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreationTime { get; init; }
}

so far my entities are using int, long, Guid and string types for keys.
As for the dynamic query applying part, I have some experience, (I will deal with it when I reach that part). For example the following code applies sort to query based on user input:
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySort<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    string propertyName,
    bool desc)
{
    try
    {
        return desc 
            ? source.OrderByDescending(propertyName) 
            : source.OrderBy(propertyName);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        // Invalid sort column
        // either sort with a default column
        // or return unsorted
        return source;
    }
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    return source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}

public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName)
{
    return source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
}

private static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var propAsObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propAsObject, parameter);
}


EF Core isn't a database driver. It's an ORM which means it deals with entities and objects, not tables. It's already generic. The problem is GetResource(string resourceName, not EF Core. You're trying to replicate the work ASP.NET Core routing would do in your ORM

I should point out that you're trying to replicate what GraphQL and OData are already doing with built-in EF Core integrations. None of the work with arbitrary tables though because it's a terrible idea. In fact OData started as a generic API over a database and was immediately rejected by developers and DBAs because IT'S IMPOSSIBLE to optimize the database for arbitrary client queries. What will YOU do when your customers complain because the client developer searches an unindexed column in a 100K rows table?

BTW your exact question can be solved by using DbContext.Find(Type,object..). The overall design though, allowing clients to make arbitrary queries,  is known to have serious issues since at least 2007 when Microsoft first proposed OData. Besides, before long you'll discover you need specialized queries for different resources

@PanagiotisKanavos - Actually they are not allowed to query anything they want. They can only query the allowed queryable columns [Queryable], they can only sort by sortable columns [Sortable]. anything else from query params will be ignored.

They can also specify which VM they want. For example the Product resource has two VMs, ProductSummeryVM for list view and ProductDetailVM for product detail view. Everything should have a sensible default and fallback for security of course.

Talking about VMs makes this "generic" APi an even worse idea. ViewModels are a UI concern. EF Core doesn't deal with ViewModels, it deals with entities, or what you'd call Models in MVVM. You can't use a Model as a ViewModel except in very simple cases. VMs exist because even in the same use case or controller, you usually need different data and rules for different views. For a Customer Model, you need different fields and rules in the New page than the Edit page.

Maybe your classes has some common interface? Only in this scenario I see usability of making for example IQueryable<IResource>. Or projection is also dynamic? We can make everything dynamic, if I understan what is needed.

This interface is also unusable. What you are trying to return at the end? Which properties? Show two typical controllers, which you are trying to generalize. We can do something really generic, but at the end only me will know what to do with this later.

OrderBy is simplest thing, check my version. What else? Filter, projection?

Actually, the projection part also seems challenging, I haven't reached that part but now that you mentioned, it doesn't seem easy to implement (if possible at all). Maybe I should tackle my problem from a different angle.

Yes, projection needs dynamic type generation, which can be borrowed from Dynamic.LINQ. Think twise, do you reaally need such complex solution? Maybe you are trying  to mimic OData?

If you are sure that all of them have the same properties, then create an interface and implement it in all your DBO types. Then, use the interface type which can take in all of your DBO types.

EF has entities, not tables. That query() method won't work with different types unless both types implement the same interface, even if it was generic

@PanagiotisKanavos ah right sorry. that was stupid of me.

first make sure you have set AutoMapper profiles that map your entities to their respective ViewModels. Then, you can use the following method in your controller or service to fetch and project data dynamically:
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly ResourceService _resourceService;

    public YourController(YourDbContext context, IMapper mapper, ResourceService resourceService)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _resourceService = resourceService;
    }

    [HttpGet("{resourceName}/{id?}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetResource(string resourceName, string? id, string sortColumn = "Id", bool isDescending = false)
    {
        if (!_resourceService.ResourceExists(resourceName))
        {
            return NotFound("Resource not found.");
        }

        var resource = _resourceService.GetResource(resourceName);
        if (resource == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Resource information could not be retrieved.");
        }

        var queryable = _context.Set(resource.Type).AsQueryable();

        // Apply dynamic filtering based on 'id' or other criteria 
        if (id != null)
        {
            // Implement your dynamic ID filtering logic here
        }

        // Apply dynamic sorting
        queryable = isDescending ? queryable.OrderByDescending(sortColumn) : queryable.OrderBy(sortColumn);

        // Determine the ViewModel type dynamically based on the resource
        Type viewModelType = GetViewModelTypeForResource(resourceName); // Implement this according to your mapping logic

        var projectedQuery = _mapper.ProjectTo(queryable, null, viewModelType);

        var resultList = await projectedQuery.ToListAsync();

        return Ok(resultList);
    }

    private Type GetViewModelTypeForResource(string resourceName)
    {
        // Implement this method to map resource names to ViewModel types.
        switch (resourceName.ToLower())
        {
            case "product":
                return typeof(ProductViewModel);
            case "order":
                return typeof(OrderViewModel);
            // Add other cases as needed
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported resource name.");
        }
    }
}


You don't need reflection to call ProjectTo, see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/1fbdf63dd99bff60b8fea096897ce0ee921f54f0/src/AutoMapper/Mapper.cs#L129
